# Not load correctly resource in OPA5

Tags: javascript, eclipse, sapui5

I create my app using OpenUI5 and I want try to integrate OPA5 to test it.
I write my test page: `TestOPA.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Opa sample for matchers</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

    <script>
      (function () {
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.qunit");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.test.Opa5");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.test.opaQunit");
        var Opa = sap.ui.test.Opa;
        var Opa5 = sap.ui.test.Opa5;

        module("Matchers");

        opaTest("Should find a Button with a matching property", function(Given, When, Then) {

          // Act
          Given.iStartMyAppInAFrame("../index.html");

          /* When.waitFor({
            viewName : "view.Main",
            controlType : "sap.m.Button",
            matchers : new sap.ui.test.matchers.PropertyStrictEquals({name : "text", value : "Changed text"}),
            success : function (aButtons) {
              ok(true, "Found the button: " + aButtons[0]);
            },
            errorMessage : "Did not find the button with the property Text equal to Changed text"
          });

          Then.iTeardownMyAppFrame(); */
        });

      })();
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="qunit-header">Opa sample for matchers</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.html` is the root of my app. Inside the flow (not at start) I load resources that are not loaded properly.

I want load the resource `http://localhost:8080/ZWebapp2/apps/appChangePwd/changePwd.js`
but the console of browser show me a error to load the resource at `http://localhost:8080/ZWebapp2/index.htmlapps/appChangePwd/changePwd.js`

On all browsers it work fine (open `http://localhost:8080/ZWebapp2/apps/appChangePwd/changePwd.js`) but I have the problem when I start `TestOPA.html`

I have the same problem if I launch the my app (`index.html`) on internal Eclipse browser by *Run as --> Web App Preview*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referencing your files with a relative path, but you want an absolute one. Here is an example of how to do this with the `jQuery.sap.require` function of UI5:
[JSBIN exmaple](http://jsbin.com/kewofegoqe/6/edit)

The require statement in the bin should always create the correct request.

In your case it seems like you want declare an absolute path which means it will start building an URL after you host (localhost:8080). An relative path starts where your index.html is located.